# Cannot assign value of type CustomViewcontroller<FirstModel> to type CustomViewcontroller<SecondModel>

Tags: swift, generics

I have two custom mappable models

```
class FirstModel: Mappable, CustomProtocol {

}

class SecondModel: FirstModel {

}
```

And another class like this

```
class SomeViewController<T: CustomProtocol>: AnotherViewConyroller<T> {

}
```

Now, in one of my viewController, i'm trying to assign different Model to reuse the current class.

```
var controller = SomeViewController<FirstModel>
controller = SomeViewController<SecondModel>
```

On the last line, i'm getting this error

```
Cannot assign value of type SomeViewController<FirstModel> to type
SomeViewController<SecondModel>
```

I don't know am i doing wrong. FirstModel is conforming to CustomProtocol and SecondModel is subclassing it.

Comment: What are you even trying to do? You create the controller here as SomeViewController<FirstModel>. Then you try to redefine it as another type? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: SomeViewController has some pagination-based networking logic. Models (FirstModel/SecondModel or any other) are then used to parse the API response. 
I want to use different model in another scenario

Comment: You won't be able to reassign your controller like that by assigning it as a different class. Look at the MVVM pattern if you wanna use updated view model for the same controller.

Comment: SomeViewController requires CustomProtocol. FirstModel is conforming to CustomProtocol and SecondModel is a subclass of FirstModel
Now here i'm declaring variable as parent type      var controller = SomeViewController<FirstModel>     Shouldn't it work? What is the issue here? Am i understanding something wrong?